# SSIS Deployment With Script Task Can't find app.config Settings in dtexec.exe.config

Tags: wcf, ssis, app-config, ws-federation

I have an SSIS package which runs fine in Visual Studio if I place the `app.config` settings in `DtsDebugHost.exe.config`.

When I deploy and include the settings also in `dtexec.exe.config` it doesn't work.  It's a WCF application which involves WS2007Federation so it would be a pain to include all this in code.  Not much about this on the Internet.  I hope I'm not on the bleeding edge.

The actual error message includes `"This might be because the configuration file was not found"`. I was hoping the `dtexec.exe.config` was the right place. Is this not right?

Comment: I have researched this over some days now and worked from the "Where is my app.config" post mentioned in the first answer below.  That's how I knew to use dtexec.exe.config.  I should have mentioned I changed the configs in both 32 and 64 bit binns.  I also changed all the configs to be the same. It still can't find the config setting for endpoint from the server yet the identical config in dtsdebughost (32bit) is found from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Manager to the rescue.  The executable from the SSISDB node on the management console is ISServerExec.exe.  I added the app.config settings to ISServerExec.exe.config and all was well.  So, in summary, I successfully used dtsdebughost.exe.config when running on Visual Studio and ISServerExec.exe.config when running the deployed package from the management console.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're changing the 32bit config, when you should be changing the 64bit config, or vice-versa.

According to [this](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Where-is-my-appconfig-for-SSIS.aspx), there are a total of five specific configuration files that you may need to change, each one is detailed below:

> **DTExec.exe.config**
>
> DTExec.exe is the standalone command line tool used for executing SSIS
>   packages, and therefore it is an execution host with an app.config
>   file.
>
> e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe.config
>
> The file can be found in both the 32-bit and 64-bit Binn folders.
>
> **DtsDebugHost.exe.config**
>
> DtsDebugHost.exe is the execution host used by Business Intelligence
>   Development Studio (BIDS) / Visual Studio when executing a package
>   from the designer in debug mode, which is the default behaviour.
>
> e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\DTS\Binn\DtsDebugHost.exe.config
>
> The file can be found in both the 32-bit and 64-bit Binn folders. This
>   may surprise some people as Visual Studio is only 32-bit, but
>   thankfully the debugger supports both. This can be set in the project
>   properties, see the Run64BitRuntime property (true or false) in the
>   Debugging pane of the Project Properties.
>
> **dtshost.exe.config**
>
> dtshost.exe is the execution host used by what I think of as the
>   built-in features of SQL Server such as SQL Server Agent
>
> e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\DTS\Binn\dtshost.exe.config
>
> This file can be found in both the 32-bit and 64-bit Binn folders
>
> **devenv.exe.config**
>
> Something slightly different is devenv.exe which is Visual Studio.
>   This configuration file may also need changing if you need a feature
>   at design-time such as in a Task Editor or Connection Manager editor.
>
> Visual Studio 2005 for SQL Server 2005  - C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config Visual Studio 2008 for
>   SQL Server 2008  - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config Visual Studio is only available for 32-bit so on a 64-bit machine you will have to look in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ only.
>
> **DTExecUI.exe.config**
>
> The DTExec UI tool can also have a configuration file and these cab be
>   found under the Tools folders for SQL Sever as shown below.
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\DTExecUI.exe C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\DTExecUI.exe
>
> A configuration file may not exist, but if you can find the matching
>   executable you know you are in the right place so can go ahead and add
>   a new file yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that but please see my comment above as I had seen the post you referred to but still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked after I restarted the server.  It seems that, while changes to dtsdebughost.exe.config can be made dynamically, changes to dtexec.exe.config require a restart before they can be recognised by an SSIS package.

Comment: No!  This appeared to work but the test data I used didn't require the app.config.  Apologies!  This is still a problem.  Why can't the deployed package see the endpoint in the config files while the package can when run in Visual Studio?